# Cache Website after login

Tags: javascript, html, caching, html5-appcache

Let me explain my situation

I have a website that is connected with mysql to verify login credentials so the user can login to his profile page. I have read about HTML 5 App cache and it suits me,but how can i force App cache to cache files for offline use after the login verification?

I know that i can store (username and password) in javascript but this is wrong because anyone can see the username and password after.

So to summarise, is it possible my Website to be stored offline with app cache but after the login page?

Comment: App Cache (or manifest) is a list of files you want to make available for offline. It usually isn't related to being logged in or not. I suppose, there's nothing to stop you dynamically generating the file after the user is logged in, with all files related to that user. For example, if you have a website where a user uploads art, you could generate a manifest for their collection. However, when you change the manifest file, the browser will try to redownload everything which may not be the desired effect. Does this help? For logins, store a randomly generated cookie.

Comment: Can't you use a combination of the output buffer and `fwrite()` to make a caching system?

Comment: The author requires a cache that will work offline. PHP's `ob*()` functions are very useful for keeping stuff fast, though I'd avoid `fwrite()` as linux and PHP can be funny about diskIO and us a proper cache such as memcache.

Comment: @DanielM oh yeah. Duh, I must have missed that requirement...OP don't use my idea!

Comment: tnx for the answers guys, i will try my best at implementing them :)

Comment: only "print" the <HTML manifest> attrib on pages you want to be offline. that said, if they can't login or see that url easily later on, it won't help much.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer in case nothing going better comes along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Cache (or manifest) is a list of files you want to make available for offline. It usually isn't related to being logged in or not.

I suppose, there's nothing to stop you dynamically generating the file after the user is logged in, with all files related to that user. For example, if you have a website where a user uploads art, you could generate a manifest for their collection.

However, when you change the manifest file, the browser will try to redownload everything which may not be the desired effect.

For logins, store a randomly generated cookie.